# How do I set a key bind with context to hide the bottom output panels?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Currently the default hotkey is Ctrl+J and it works to toggle (show and hide) any panel that may be occupying the space (Output, Terminal, etc.)

What I want to do is make Esc the hotkey to only hide the panel if already shown (not toggle). This is what I have right now in *keybindings.json*, but of course it will toggle the panel back and forth.

```
{ "key": "escape",    "command": "workbench.action.togglePanel" }
```

Is there a "when" context I can use that states the panel being shown so I can have this hotkey only work when shown?

```
{ "key": "escape",    "command": "workbench.action.togglePanel",
                      "when": "__________??______________"       }
```

If not "when", is there a "command" that only closes active panel instead of toggle? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no `when` condition which indicates the panel's visibility. Even if there would be such a condition and you'd bind <kbd>Esc</kbd> to `workbench.action.togglePanel` then you would probably get conflicts with other commands bound to <kbd>Esc</kbd> as their `when` conditions could be fulfilled at the same time.

The default keybindings (at least on a Windows machine) contain 15 commands bound to <kbd>Esc</kbd> in different conditions. I guess it's much easier to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> for toggling the panel then adjusting the `when` conditions for all the other 15 keybinds in order to get the behaviour you want in all cases.